# Apply two drop shadow effects to a TextBlock in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, effects, textblock

I'd like to apply a glow effect to a `TextBlock` on mouseover.  I figured the quickest and simplest way to do this would be to use a `DropShadowEffect` and change the settings so it's directly behind the text, which works a treat.

However, the `TextBlock` already has a `DropShadowEffect` on it, so when I mouseover the 'glow' effect replaces the drop shadow.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932999/silverlight-4-how-to-apply-multiple-effects-to-an-element) of wrapping the `TextBlock` in a `Grid` and applying the glow to the grid, but that appears to cascade and override the drop shadow on the `TextBlock`.

Is there any way to effectively apply two drop shadows to the same element, or is there an alternative way to implement glow on a `TextBlock` that's about as simple as this method?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932999/silverlight-4-how-to-apply-multiple-effects-to-an-element

Comment: @Erno: Yes, cheers! That's the solution I *tried* to link to in the question! :)  It's updated now.  I think the issue is presumably with two effects of the same type.

Comment: I assumed you'd be able to create some sort of composite effect that contains 2 drop shadows (drop shadow itself appears to be a "copy and move" effect and a blur effect) but I cant work out how. If you dissassemble the drop shadow there isn't actually implementation in it. It's all properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing this by adding a secondary `ContentPresenter` with `Visibility="Collapsed"` and attaching a drop shadow to that, with the following settings:

```
<DropShadowEffect Direction="0" BlurRadius="10" 
                  ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.6" Color="White" />
```

I then made this visible in the `MouseOver` state to create the glow effect.

Comment: does it need to be a ContentPresenter? how about a simpler Rectangle?

Comment: @Xin: I would imagine that a rectangle would give me a rectangular glow - I'm adding a glow to text that's passed in as the Content property.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see you actually meant the glow for the text!

Answer (score 0):

[Did you have a look at this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932999/silverlight-4-how-to-apply-multiple-effects-to-an-element)

Different effects are possible but the same will apparently overwrite.
The only other solution I see is to write a PixelShaderEffect that contains the required effect.

Comment: As far as I can see that would require me to learn HSLS which doesn't really fit with the '_as simple as this method_' bit of the question!

Comment: I know but I thought that while my answer is 'no' it would be nice to add an way that does make it possible. 'Easy' is also very subjective. Perhaps you could even find a ready-made Pixelshader (http://shazzam-tool.com contains many examples) and adding a PixelShaderEffect is as easy as adding an effect.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, I was just ideally looking for a way to do it in Blend.  It seems like a lot of work to do a fairly simple thing! Shazzam looks good if it needs to be done with pixel shaders, I'll check that out next week, cheers :)

Comment: @Town: don't worry, I didn't see it as criticism. Pixel shaders aren't that hard to make and there are lots of resources so IHMO a very valid option if you really need it. Shazzam is a great tool and has some nice tutorials too!